# Когда/Почему используется глагол «быть» в прошедшем времени с другим прошедшим глаголом?

Tags: грамматика

Я читаю книгу Пелевина «Омон Ра» и несколько раз видел такую конструкцию, типа:

> [...] я **положил было руку на трубку**, но вспомнил, что уже заткнул уши ватой;

Почему используется здесь «было», то есть, как отличается «я положил было руку...» и просто «я положил руку...»?

Comment: Было - частица, а не глагол( как, например, "бы" - частица сослагательного накланения). Но в отличие от "бы" - предположения, что что-то могло бы случится следующим образом, "было" говориться, когда чего не произошло или произошло не так, как ожидалось. Когда герой положил руку на трубку( то есть хотел позвонить), то вдруг вспомнил/подумал и не позвонил, а стал заниматься другим, что посчитал более важным...

Comment: I **started to pick up the phone**, but remembered I'd already plugged my ears with absorbent cotton.